# Microsoft Edge Offline Installer

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-server

I am trying to install Microsoft Edge on an offline Microsoft Server 2019 to use for some testing. I downloaded the latest Microsoft Edge Offline installer. When I run it, it pops a box that says:

> Microsoft Edge works best with the latest Windows Updates. Once you
> download updates and restart your device, rerun the installer.

The server is patched to the latest patches. Yet it still gives me this message. How can I get it installed?

Comment: You can either enable the group policy that prevents Edge from updating (the idea here is the message would go away) or if you can use [WSUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/278354/wsus-microsoft-edge-update.html) to throw Edge updates. It’s also possible the original installation failed. Can you provide logs?

Comment: @Ramhound I have the updates for Edge enabled in WSUS. But I can't update what isn't installed. Where am I looking for the log?